# How to populate MongoDB database using FastAPI

Tags: mongodb, fastapi

I have a Pydantic model which I would like to populate beforehand to list when opening an application. I am using a MongoDB database and FastAPI. For a relational database this could be done using Alembic. What can I use for a No-SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

> What can I use for a No-SQL database?

For connecting to MongoDB database from FastAPI you could utilise [Motor: Asynchronous Python driver for MongoDB](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

For example:

```py
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(os.environ["MONGODB_URI"])
db = client.database_name
```

As you're using [Pydantic](https://pydantic.dev/), one thing to note is MongoDB uses `_id`, but in Python, underscores at the start of attributes have special meaning. If you have an attribute on your model that starts with an underscore, Pydantic assume that it is a private variable, meaning you will not be able to assign it a value. To get around this, name the field `id` but give it an alias of `_id`.

See also [Blog: Getting Started with MongoDB and FastAPI](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/python-quickstart-fastapi/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I want to start with specific values. Is there a specific way to populate the db or is it ok to  just do inserts after `init_beanie()`?

Comment: Hi, you would have to do inserts with this. Even if you shared the same data models, you would have to read from the source data base to the target database.